# How to record sound in the background in android using Delphi 10

Tags: android, service, firemonkey, delphi-xe

Hell, I am trying to test Delphi 10 Android background services, i am trying to record sound in the background using local service,however, when the service starts its dosent recored sound to `Test.caf` , my codes : 
the App

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
   TLocalServiceConnection.StartService('RecService');
```

The service code :

```
  function TAndroidServiceDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender:     TObject;
 const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
 begin
 Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
 FMicrophone := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;

 { and attempt to record to 'test.caf' file }
 FMicrophone.FileName := '/sdcard/1/test.caf';
 FMicrophone.StartCapture;
 sleep(5000);
     FMicrophone.StopCapture;
```

any help appreciated many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Android Services in RAD Studio don't work with FMX... modules. To work with media need to use low level modules.

I realized the issue that method (hope it will usefull):

```
uses
  ...
  AndroidApi.JNI.Media, // JMediaRecorder
  AndroidApi.Timer, // Timer
  ...;

Const
  TimerInterval = 1000;
  TimerCounterSecLimit = 10;

type
  TDM = class(TAndroidService)
    ...
  private
    FTimerHandle: Integer;
    FRecording: Boolean;

    procedure StartRecord;
    procedure StopRecord;

    procedure StartTimer;
    procedure StopTimer;
  public
    FAudioRec: JMediaRecorder;
  end;

procedure TDM.AndroidServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTimerHandle := 0;
  FTimerCounter := 0;
  FRecording := false;
end;

procedure TDM.AndroidServiceDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StopTimer;
  StopRecord;
end;

function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject; const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if Intent.getAction.equalsIgnoreCase(StringToJString('StopIntent')) then
  begin
    StopTimer;
    StopRecord;
    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_NOT_STICKY; // don't reload service
    Log('- service stoped', []);
  end
  else begin
    if not FRecording then
    begin
        Log('... sound record to be started', []);
        StartRecord;
        StartTimer;
    end;

    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY; // rerun service if it stops
    Log('+ Service started', []);
  end;
end;

procedure TDM.StartRecord;
begin
  StopRecord;

  FAudioRec := TJMediaRecorder.Create;
  FAudioRec.setAudioSource(TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.MIC);
  FAudioRec.setOutputFormat(TJMediaRecorder_OutputFormat.JavaClass.THREE_GPP);
  FAudioRec.setAudioEncoder(TJMediaRecorder_AudioEncoder.JavaClass.AMR_NB);
  FAudioRec.setOutputFile(StringToJString(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedMusicPath, 'myrecord.3gp')));
  try
    FAudioRec.Prepare();
    FAudioRec.start;
    FRecording := True;
    Log('+ Start record to %s', [TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedMusicPath, 'myrecord.3gp')]);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Log('- Error in mic recording: %s', [E.Message]);
  end;
end;

procedure TDM.StopRecord;
begin
  if Assigned(FAudioRec) then
  begin
    if FRecording then
    begin
      FRecording := false;
      try
        FAudioRec.stop();
        FAudioRec.release();
        Log('- Mic recording is stoped');
      except
        on E: Exception do
          Log('- Error in mic stop recording: %s', [E.Message]);
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    FRecording := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TDM.WaitComplete(TimerId: Integer);
begin
  if FTimerCounter < TimerCounterSecLimit then
  begin
    Log('+++ Timer is triggered %d time.', [FTimerCounter]);
    inc(FTimerCounter);
  end
  else
    StopTimer;
end;

procedure TDM.StartTimer;
begin
  FTimerCounter := 0;
  if FTimerHandle = 0 then
  begin
    FTimerHandle := AndroidTimerCreate;
    AndroidTimerSetInterval(FTimerHandle, TimerInterval);
  end;
  AndroidTimerSetHandler(WaitComplete);

  Log('+ Timer started', []);
end;

procedure TDM.StopTimer;
begin
  if FTimerHandle > 0 then
  begin
    Log('... MIC recording to be stopped');
    StopRecord;

    AndroidTimerSetHandler(nil);
    Log('- Timer stoped', []);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of permissions you enabled?
Does the service work, sound file created?

1. It needs to start а TThread instead of Sleep().
2. Module FMX.Media.pas->FMX.Media.Android.pas use Android activities, and it doesn't work in android services. And service should not run. It needs to use alternate methods to work with AudioCaptureDevice.

Comment: record permission, yes it works,  no sound files created !, the service still running until terminated by user